# Sharepoint permissions - see main site but not subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

is it possible in sharepoint to see the company's main sharepoint site but not subsites? For an example the "homepage"- Main site is companyname.sharepoint.com and on this site there are links to other sites and projects. How can I set the permission so that the user can open companyname.sharepoint.com but if he clicks on some project or link on the main site (he can see the link) he can't see the link/project's content? In short everybody should see the main site but not have access to the projects that are there listed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want you should stop inheriting permissions in the subsites.

Then you can remove all the reading permissions for the users in the subsites.

Doing users will not see and cannot enter the subsites